# Performance of Google v7-palette library

Tags: android, palette

Google provides a nice API called palette for finding the primary color in an image. It's pretty neat in code usage, but I was concerned about the performance impact it will have when I use it for each image in a recycler view.

This brings me to the question what is the runtime of the algorithm used by  palette in terms of width and height pixels of the image.